# GCP Alert notification is sending only once

Tags: google-cloud-platform, notifications, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring, google-alerts

I setup Alert Monitoring for pubsub subscription like below:

[image: Alert for Unacked messages count]

I was expecting this to fire every 2 minutes, since the condition is met throughout.

But I got the notification only one time. I also tried with `duration` 1 minute. Still no luck.
What am I doing wrong here?
Or my understanding of these terms may be wrong?

What I want is:
For every 2 minutes, when count of un-acked message count is > x, trigger an alert.

Note: I just masked the `filter` field here, which is a `subscription_id`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current monitoring set up is working as intended since you only have **a single time series and a single condition**. As per [alert notification docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#number-of-notifications):

> You can only receive multiple notifications if any of the following
> are true:
>
> All conditions are met:
>
> When all conditions are met, then for each
> time series that results in a condition being met, the policy sends a
> notification and creates an incident. For example, if you have a
> policy with two conditions and each condition is monitoring one time
> series, then when the policy is triggered, you receive two
> notifications and you see two incidents.
>
> Any condition is met:
>
> The policy sends a notification each time a new
> combination of conditions is met. For example, assume that ConditionA
> is met, that an incident opens, and that a notification is sent. If
> the incident is still open when a subsequent measurement meets both
> ConditionA and ConditionB, then another notification is sent.
>
> If you create the policy by using the Google Cloud Console, then the
> default behavior is to **send a notification** when the condition is
> met.

Lastly the purpose of ["Period"](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#alignment) is to just increase the data points in the chart and is not related to triggering a notification multiple times until it is below the threshold. Thus it is not possible send continuous notifications until the monitored data is below the threshold.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!