# GCP Alert Filters criteria for multiple resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filtering, monitoring, google-cloud-pubsub, gcp-alerts

I want to be able to filter multiple subscriptions when setting up GCP Alert. Can someone explain?

I can add multiple filter entries. But they are all combined with `AND`. So all of them have to be met, and not I wanted.

Ex: Lets say I have `subscription-1`, `ad-subscription-1`, `auto-subscription-2`, `my-subscription-dev`.

I want to setup alerts for only `auto-subscription-2` and `my-subscription-dev`
How to specify that in the filter criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be using your configuration [form your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729595/gcp-alert-notification-is-sending-only-once), click on **Query Editor** and it will show you the equivalent query of your current settings.

[image]

In the query, there is a line `| filter (resource.subscription_id == 'auto-subscription-2)`. Simply add `||` and include your subscription you want to include in the filter. The whole line should look like this after applying the OR expression:

```
| filter (resource.subscription_id == 'auto-subscription-2' || resource.subscription_id == 'my-subscription-dev')
```

The whole query should look like this:

```
fetch pubsub_subscription
| metric 'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages'
| filter (resource.subscription_id == 'auto-subscription-2' || resource.subscription_id == 'my-subscription-dev' )
| group_by 2m,
    [value_num_undelivered_messages_mean: mean(value.num_undelivered_messages)]
| every 2m
| condition val() > 5 '1'
```

NOTE:For testing purposes I originally have 3 subscriptions (test-sub,test-sub-2,test-sub-3) and I filtered test-sub and test-sub-3:
[image]